# how to hide calendar icon after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, vb.net

**This is the HTML code for the date field**

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="txtExpiryDate" runat="server" Width="80px" MaxLength="10" CssClass="fromDate" />
```

**This is the HTML code for Submit button**

```html
  <asp:Button ID="cmdSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="Email_Credit" />
```

**This is the js for datepicker**

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Control/DatepickerValidator.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        AddCalendarHandler('<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Images/icon-calendar.gif") %>');
    });

    
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    if (prm != null) {
        prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
            if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
              AddCalendarHandler('<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Images/icon-calendar.gif") %>');
            }
  
        });
    };

</script>
```

**This is how i disable the dete field**

Private Sub DisableControl(ByVal IsDisable As Boolean)

```
 txtExpiryDate.Enabled = Not IsDisable
```

End Sub

all working fine but the the icon cannot be disabled. please guide me how to disable the calendar icon either via vb or js.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to disable it via vb

txtExpiryDate.CssClass = IIf(IsDisable, "", "fromDate")

this will disable the css class called from the textbox.